# QGIS -Split vector layer tool not generating an output

Tags: qgis, splitting, vector-layer

I'm trying to split a vector layer into new layers based on one field. The field is string type but when I run the tool, a message saying 'Creation of field fid failed (OGR error: Wrong field type for fid)' comes up. Before running I created a folder to store the output layers.

Any idea about what I have to change or what the right type field is, please?

The output should be many layers as unique values the field have.

Comment: Well, what is your field type for your FID field?, please check the properties of your layer in QGIS. As far as I am aware it should be an Integer64

Comment: FID field was string and I changed to Integer64 and finally it works. It would be useful to add a note on the tool, to specify the type of field that you need. Great, many thanks for your help! @MarcM

Comment: Glad it worked. I have adapted my comment in an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for future reference:
Change your `field type` of FID to `Integer64` instead of `String`.